# Kohana добавление данных в связанную таблицу

Tags: orm, kohana, php

Здравствуйте, имеется таблица с адресами и номерами один адрес может иметь несколько номеров а каждый номер только один адрес.

Имею 2 моделя

```
class Model_Address extends ORM {
    protected $_has_many = array(
        'phones' => array(
            'model' => 'phone',
            'foreign_key' => 'address_id',
        ),
    );
}

class Model_Phone extends ORM {
    protected $_table_name = 'phones';
    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'address' => array(
            'model' => 'address',
            'foreign_key' => 'address_id',
        ),
    );
}
```

Теперь при редактировании адреса вывожу все номера относящиеся к данному адресу и при нажатии сохранить получаю все данные адреса и массив номеров относящийся к нему сохраняю данные адреса потом удаляю все номера относящиеся к нему и передаю массив новых номеров

```
$orm_address->save();
$orm_address->remove('phones');
$orm_address->add('phones', $data_address['phone']);
```

в чём проблема данные адреса изменяет но уже на следующем шаге выводить ошибку не может удалить и добавить новые данные заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если посмотреть [исходники](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/ORM#add), то метод `add` добавляет только связь между двумя таблицами, а не новую запись. Иными словами этот метод пригоден только для **HABTM** связей (has-and-belong-to-many).

Попробуйте использовать менее красивые варианты типа:

```
foreach($orm_address->phones->find_all() as $phone) $phone->delete();
```

Ну или чтобы было меньше запросов используйте `Query_Builder`.

Для вставки нового значения видимо придёться сделать вот так (вам надо будет это зациклить):

```
$phone = ORM::factory('phone')->values(array(
    'phone'    => '8-800-2222222',
    'address'  => $orm_address,
));
$phone->create();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну я так пробовал удалить все записи удалял а вот вставка новых записей приводила только добавлению одной записи (самой последней который в массиве)

```
$orm_phone = ORM::factory('phone');

foreach ($orm_phone->where('address_id', '=', $id)->find_all() as $phone) {
    $phone->delete();
}

$phones_data = array();
foreach ($data_address['phone'] as $v) {
    $orm_phone->values(array(
        'address_id' => $id,
        'phone' => $v,
     ));
     $orm_phone->save();
}
```

Comment: я не просто так не стал выносить `ORM::factory('phone')` в отдельную переменную... В данном случае в начале каждой итерации вставки записи вы должны очищать модель:

    $orm_phone->clear();